# maven-assembly-plugin cannot package dependencies as expected

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I used maven to package my jar.I wish to make a jar called sdk-issue-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-distribution.jar with it's inner file structure as follows,in this way it can work well when it is imported to a project.

```
sdk-issue-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-distribution.jar

|--myJar.jar
|--lib
    |--jackson.jar
    |--httpclient.jar
```

but the result is that  they are packaged into an unwanted folder named sdk-issue-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-distribution.Thus the structure is:

```
sdk-issue-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-distribution.jar

|--sdk-issue-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-distribution
    |--myJar.jar
    |--lib
        |--jackson.jar
        |--httpclient.jar
```

As a result,when added to a project,I cannot import it.

my pom.xml used maven-assembly-plugin:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.yonyou</groupId>
<artifactId>sdk-issue</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>sdk-issue</name>

<properties>
    <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
    <gson.version>2.7</gson.version>
    <httpcomponents.version>4.5</httpcomponents.version>
</properties>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <!-- 编译插件 -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- jar打包相关插件 -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <!-- The configuration of the plugin -->
            <configuration>
                <!-- Configuration of the archiver -->
                <archive>

                    <!-- 生成的jar中，不要包含pom.xml和pom.properties这两个文件 -->
                    <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>

                    <!-- Manifest specific configuration -->
                    <manifest>
                        <!-- 是否要把第三方jar放到manifest的classpath中 -->
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <!-- 生成的manifest中classpath的前缀，因为要把第三方jar放到lib目录下，所以classpath的前缀是lib/ -->
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        <!-- 应用的main class -->
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <!-- 过滤掉不希望包含在jar中的文件 -->
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>assembly\assembly.xml</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>assembly\assembly.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
                <!-- <descriptorRefs> <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef> 
                    </descriptorRefs> -->
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-sources</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- httpclient，发送HTTP请求 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>${httpcomponents.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- gson，json转换工具 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>${gson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- jjwt，Java Web Token签名工具包 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
        <version>0.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- bcprov-jdk15on，PEM格式私钥证书读取工具类 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
        <version>1.52</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

here is assembly.xml:

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">
<id>distribution</id>
<formats>
    <format>jar</format>
</formats>
<!--<fileSets>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>${project.basedir}\src\main\resources</directory>
        <outputDirectory>\</outputDirectory>
    </fileSet>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>${project.basedir}\src\bin</directory>
        <outputDirectory>\bin</outputDirectory>
    </fileSet>
</fileSets>-->
<fileSets>
<fileSet>  
        <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>  
        <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>  
        <includes>  
            <include>*.jar</include>  
        </includes>  
    </fileSet>  
</fileSets>  
<dependencySets>  
    <dependencySet>  
        <!-- 
           不使用项目的artifact，第三方jar不要解压，打包进zip文件的lib目录 
       -->  
        <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>  
        <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>  
        <unpack>false</unpack>  
    </dependencySet>  
</dependencySets> </assembly>
```

How to take them out of the unwanted folder so that the jar can work correctly when imported into a project?

Comment: try to remove this line: `<directory>${project.build.directory}</directory> ` or Change it to `<directory>/</directory>`

Comment: it does't work.I used ` <descriptorRefs> <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef> 
                    </descriptorRefs>` .Although not perfectly.